# Excel 2010 CountIf function only works with debug

Tags: excel, countif

I have the following excel function:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($B22:$BA22,$BY$4:$BY$49))
```

The first range B22 - BA22 is filled with formulas that read data from other spreadsheets.

The values displayed in those cells are like "1234Pass", "3456Fail".

The values in the second range, BY4 - BY49, contain all of the possible Fail values. Those are typed in manually. All Cells are formatted as general.

The SUM formula above always displays 0 in the cell. However if I click in the formula bar and press F9, the correct value is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check if `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` from immediate window. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Enter the formula as an array formula -- hold down **ctrl+shift** while you hit **enter**.  Excel will put braces **{...}** around the formula if you do it correctly.

Comment: @pnuts  No Problem.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the formula as an array formula -- hold down `ctrl+shift` while you hit `enter`. Excel will put braces `{...}` around the formula if you do it correctly